# How can I use FundAmerica RESTful API in PHP?

Tags: php, rest

I am trying to use the [FundAmerica](http://www.fundamerica.com/) REST API. The documentation can be found [here](https://apps.fundamerica.com/support/documentation), but I don't understand how to use it. I found a [library](https://github.com/fundamerica/fundamerica_php) on Github, but see a lot of errors when I try to use it:

> Strict Standards: Declaration of ACHToken::delete() should be compatible with that of APIResource::delete()
>
> Strict Standards: Declaration of ACHToken::find() should be compatible with that of APIResource::find()

Could someone please explain to me how I can either:

- Avoid these errors when using the library?
- Use the API in PHP *without* using the library?

Also, could someone please explain what this means:

```
curl https://apps.fundamerica.com/api/example_objects \
-u 7Tft-uNlLJtgJezak2ywLINr7qHFa18i: \
-X POST \
-d name='OBJECT NAME'
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need to use a library for this - simply send a request (via [`cURL`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CURL), [`XMLHttpRequest`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest), or something else) to the relevant URL (such as https://sandbox.fundamerica.com/api/offerings) with the relevant parameters (such as `amount='5000000'`).

If you're using PHP, the [`http_request()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-request.php) function seems to be what you need.

Comment: ok, n what are these `-u 7Tft-uNlLJtgJezak2ywLINr7qHFa18i: \     
-X POST \   
-d name='OBJECT NAME' `  How to send them using cURL..any help please in header or what n how

Comment: I am using this `$curl = curl_init();
                $url = " https://sandbox.fundamerica.com/api/";
                $user = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";  
                curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
                 curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $user);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
                $resp = curl_exec($curl);
    var_dump($resp);
                curl_close($curl);` but not working for me